# Integrals over $\mathbb{R}^N$

Tags: measure-theory, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, lebesgue-measure

The integral over $\mathbb{R}^N$
$$\int (1+|x|)^{-s} dx \hspace{1 cm} and \hspace{1 cm} \int (1+ |x|^2)^{-s/2} dx$$
are convergent if and only if $s>n$; in particular, we have the precise estimate $\int (1+|x|^2)^{-n} dx\leq \pi^n$.

I am unable to undersatnd the statement and also in the book proof was written partially. Please help me to understand this.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- Where does the issue of convergence arise? Is it near the origin or near $\infty$?
- Think first about $N=1$. This is a standard result (called integral p-test...whatever it is called it is a simple matter to evaluate the integral $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^s}\,dx$ and decide for what values of $s$ the integral converges).
- Use spherical coordinates and Fubini's theorem to change the $N$-dimensional integral to a 1-dimesional problem, and then apply the result of $N=1$.

Comment: sir convergence is not clear. Can you explain this in details?

Comment: @golden If you're having trouble thinking about this, assume $N=1$ for simplicity. Now, what do you know about $\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{(1+|x|)^s}$? Is this finite or infinite?

Comment: yes I got that it is finite.

Comment: Ok, so more generally, $\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}\frac{dx}{(1+|x|)^s}$ is finite if and only if $\int_{|x|\geq 1}\frac{dx}{(1+|x|)^s}$ is finite (because like we just established, the issue of convergence is NOT near the origin. THe function is nice an continuous everywhere). Now, use spherical cooridnates what does $\int_{|x|\geq 1}\frac{dx}{(1+|x|)^s}$ equal?

Comment: ok sir i am trying to show this

Comment: sir, can you explain more abouth how to use spherical cooridnates?

Comment: @golden let $x=r\omega$ where $r\in [0,1)$ and $\omega\in S^{n-1}$ (the unit sphere). This parametrizes the exterior of the unit ball: $|x|\geq 1$ using the radial part and angular part. So, $\int_{|x|\geq 1}\frac{dx}{(1+|x|)^s}=\int_1^{\infty}\int_{S^{n-1}}\frac{r^{n-1}\,d\omega \,dr}{(1+r)^s}$. There's a whole bunch of excess constants here. Try to figure out the essential portions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123077/discussion-between-golden-and-peek-a-boo).

Comment: sir can you write the proof of this and send to me because i tried 2 days but I can not get proper poof? Thanks in advance! @peek-a-boo